# Что собой представляет проверка на внимательность и как она работает?

Tags: поддержка, faq, очередь-проверок

Проверяя первое сообщения нового участника я получил следующее сообщение:

> #### Поздравляем!
>
> Это всего лишь проверка, чтобы оценить вашу внимательность. **Вы прошли проверку.**

- Какова цель проверки?
- Как работает аудит?
- Что произойдет, если я не пройду проверку?
- Учитываются ли проверки при присваивании знака «Инспектор»?
- Считает ли проверяющий на автопилоте электрических овечек перед сном?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/)».</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### Какова цель проверки?

Проверка (известная также как аудит) призвана помочь новым проверяющим усовершенствовать навыки модерации и, в то же время, напомнить более опытным участникам о необходимости внимательного отношения к тому, что они проверяют. Некоторые участники имеют привычку голосовать за всё, что проверяют, независимо от качества; сообщения низкого качества имеющие высокий рейтинг не идут на пользу системе. Именно поэтому был добавлен «аудит» — чтобы участники все-таки обращали внимание на то, за что они голосуют.

В настоящее время данная функциональность активна только на больших сайтах ([Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com), [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/),  [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) и [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)).

### Как работает аудит?

- В очереди **первых сообщений**, **запоздалых ответов** и **сообщений низкого качества** система показывает проверяющему сообщение, ранее удаленное модератором (отмеченное как спам, не содержащее ответ на вопрос, либо сообщение крайне низкого качества) или же высокую ценность (высокий рейтинг, отсутствие голосов «против» и т. п.).
- В очереди **голоса за закрытие** и **голоса за повторное открытие** система показывает проверяющему вопрос, который, «по мнению» системы и на основании определенных критериев, должен быть открыт или закрыт (вопросы, имеющие высокий рейтинг при отсутствии голосов за закрытие, быстро закрытые вопросы, не имеющие ответов и т. п.).
- В очереди **предлагаемых правок** система показывает проверяющему сообщения со случайным образом сгенерированными правками, а именно – со вставленными в соответствии с алгоритмом цепей Маркова словами, которые, на первый взгляд, вписываются в текст публикации, но фактически являются бессмыслицей, его искажающей.

Если участник не проходит аудит, появляется сообщение о том, что проверка не пройдена, с просьбой к участнику быть более внимательным в будущем. Если участник справляется с проверкой, никаких действий не происходит – участник продолжает проверку. В некоторых задачах по проверке участнику сообщают, что тест пройден и благодарят за уделенное время и предоставленную обратную связь.

Результаты проверок фиксируются для последующего анализа. Полученные данные могут просматривать только модераторы (♦) и сотрудники компании – участникам, даже с высокой репутацией, они недоступны.

### Что произойдет, если я не пройду проверку?

В большинстве случаев [ничего](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me/156942#comment452398_156942). Вам сообщат, почему данного рода сообщение неприемлемо и что именно было необходимо сделать, а затем разрешат продолжать проверку.

> СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.
>
> Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить вашу
>   внимательность. Вы не прошли проверку. Ваша проверка оказалась
>   неправильной. Это было хорошее сообщение, поэтому вам стоило оставить
>   его без изменений или даже проголосовать в его пользу.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста,
>   уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые
>   инструкции.

Повторяющиеся ошибки, особенно идущие подряд, могут [привести к приостановке ваших привилегий проверяющего](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/why-am-i-getting-the-message-youve-failed-too-many-recent-review-audits#158675) на неделю или более, в зависимости от частоты подобных ошибок. Алгоритмы продолжают совершенствоваться на основе анализа поступающих данных, чтобы определять, какие действия в конкретных случаях будут наиболее эффективны.

### Учитываются ли проверки при присваивании знака «Инспектор»?

Пройденный аудит расценивается как успешная проверка и учитываются при присвоении знака «Инспектор». В случае неудачи аудит не учитывается и не уменьшает ваш прогресс – все остается, как было.

### Считает ли проверяющий на автопилоте электрических овечек перед сном?

Автопроверяющие не спят. Они *ждут.*

#### Важное замечание:

*Информация, содержащаяся в данном ответе, при дальнейшем улучшении системы правок может меняться.*

Comment: _"Результаты проверок фиксируются для последующего анализа. Полученные данные могут просматривать только модераторы (♦) и сотрудники компании – участникам, даже с высокой репутацией, они недоступны."_ - по прямой ссылке доступны же. Или речь о каких-то других результатах?

Comment: @Qwertiy Как я понимаю, речь идет про статистику проверок по каждому участнику.

Comment: Наконец-то объяснили, благодарю! А про овец не понял.

Comment: @user207618 это отсылка к книге Филиппа Дика "Снятся ли андроидм электроовцы" (do androids dream of electric sheep)