# Смешные правки от духа сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, дух-сообщества, аудит

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/201724 почему дух сообщества предлагает такие странные и смешные правки? Я бы понимал какой-то анонимный юзер. Особенно рассмешила фраза *"как табор цыган"*. с чем это может связано, или это система защиты от ботов которые говорят что все нормально?

Answer (score 9):

> или это система защиты от ботов которые говорят что все нормально?

Совершенно верно. На самом деле такой правки никто не предлагал, даже Дух. Это сфабрикованная заведомо неправильная правка со сфабрикованным досье.

Если её принять, система погрозит вам пальчиком и расскажет, почему вы неправы. Но правка не будет применена. Других санкций за единичный провал аудита не будет.

Answer (score 8):

Это [аудит (проверка на внимательность)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3563/181472).

Специальный алгоритм берет вопрос или ответ, добавляет в него фрагменты других вопросов и ответов, подписывает анонимным пользователем и подсовывает в очередь предлагаемых правок.

За последний месяц в этой очереди было 103 таких проверки.
Участники провалили 7 из них.

---

Кстати, [вот откуда пришёл табор цыган](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/697569/181472).

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, у меня так-же есть мнение описаное выше.

Comment: ..описано ниже*

Comment: @Duoxx проще вместо расчёта на порядок ответов сказать "в моём ответе" (или даже сделать ссылку).

Comment: вы правы https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6001/245150

Answer (score 4):

Как написано в описании духа сообщества он следит чтобы сайт был чист, а также важно выделить для вашего вопроса

> владею всеми предлагаемыми правками от анонимных пользователей

Это означает что если какой-либо анонимный пользователь оставил правку содержащую: глупости, спам, попытку ответа и другие причины отмена правки это присваивается Духу сообщества для проверки ботов в очереди проверок.

---

Привет, Мир!

Я — выдуманный персонаж, процесс-демон, который помогает поддерживать чистоту сайта!

Обычно я:

- случайным образом раз в час поднимаю старые вопросы без принятых ответов и ответов с положительным рейтингом в общем списке для того, чтобы они получили чуточку дополнительного внимания;
- являюсь автором общих вопросов и ответов, так чтобы все баллы, заработанные в них, отправлялись на благо бескрайней пустоты Вселенной;
- являюсь автором голосов «против» в сообщениях, содержащих спам, которые удаляются раз и навсегда;
- владею всеми предлагаемыми правками от анонимных пользователей;
- [удаляю «заброшенные» вопросы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/).