# Проверка при голосовании за закрытие вопроса

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

При голосовании за закрытие вопроса [Зачем нужно ключевое слово yield в **iter**?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483215) мной была выбрана причина с возможным [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037883). После чего я получил следующее предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как оказалось на вопрос уже был дан ответ, который в проверке не отображался и набрал несколько голосов.
Я не претендую на знатока Python, но на мой взгляд по предложенной ссылке объяснялся yield и сферы его применения.

Вопрос: где я был не прав? Чем мне это грозит? Не выглядит ли это подставой для проверяющих? А нужны ли эти проверки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однократные ошибки в очереди проверок точно ничем не грозят. Многократные [должны блокировать доступ к очередям проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11751/176217), но вроде бы по факту не блокируют.

Наполнение для очередей проверок формируются автоматически на основании имеющихся связей. Если на вопрос есть хорошо оцененный ответ, и вопрос не закрыт (например, как дубликат), то выбор закрытия в очереди проверок будет считаться ошибкой.

[Проверки нужны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3563/176217), чтобы не терять бдительность, но они не всегда достаточно хороши, к сожалению, и могут вызывать вопросы, подобные этому.

Comment: "Если на вопрос есть хорошо оцененный ответ" - какая разница вообще?)) 100500 вопросов, которые были закрыты после того как на них дали ответы. Как по мне это неправильное условие для проверки бдительности

Comment: @EzioMercer все возмущения надо писать на англо меты. Но там быстро закроют дубликатом или заминусят :)

Comment: Я уже понял по своему горькому опыту... Просто был крик души :)